# Can predicate delegate simply be called as a boolean delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, boolean, predicate

Delegates, yes I am trying to understand the use of this concept, what problems it helps to solve in C#. So far, I really like the Decoupling facility it provides code with. Then I came across Predicate Delegates. According to [this MSDN library article it *shows* they are, delegates that takes any data type paramter and returns a bool type value...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx).

It also says, this particular delegate takes generics, `<T>`, can it be said then any Type...

So is it correct to say Predicate Delegate is simply a Boolean Delegate? That means any Delegate with Boolean Return Type? Or is there more to it for specifying with a different name: Predicate Delegates..?

E.g.

```
delegate bool BooleanDelegate(anytype parameter);
BooleanDelegate bd = new BooleanDelegate(yesno);     
//assuming parameter type is int
MessageBox.Show(bd.Invoke(2).ToString());

public bool yesno(anytype parameter)
{      
   If (parameter == 2)
    {
       return true;
    }
   Else
    {
       return false;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, a predicate is a boolean-valued function. So yes, any function that returns a boolean is a predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a `Predicate<T>` represents a method which take in one parameter of type `T`, and returns `bool`. For example, a `Predicate<string>` represents a method that takes in a `string` and returns a `bool`.

For example:

```
Predicate<string> p = String.IsNullOrEmpty;  // this static method has the correct signature and return type
```

with which you can say

```
bool answer = p("your words");
```

The generics means that `T` can have a different meaning in different situations. So you don't have to make a whole bunch of delegate types like `StringPredicate`, `DateTimePredicate`, `BicyclePredicate`, and so on, but you can use `Predicate<DateTime>`, `Predicate<Bicycle>`, ...

A `Predicate<T>` has the same signature and return type as a `Func<T, bool>` (introduced in .NET version 3.5). Both are contravariant in `T`.

You:

> So is it correct to say Predicate Delegate is simply a Boolean Delegate?

Its signature has to be correct. There must be exactly one parameter (not zero, or two or more). The parameter must not be `ref` or `out`. The parameter must have the correct type `T` (but the meaning of `T` can differ). For example a method that takes in a `Bicycle` could be a `Predicate<Bicycle>`, but not a `Predicate<DateTime>`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it took me time to experiement and have more questiosn on the same line :) You said ***The parameter must not be ref or out.***, so it has to be `param`?

Comment: When we look at the [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) of `Predicate<>` we see that parameter `T obj` does _not_ carry the `params` modifyer. It couldn't, because we don't know if `T` is an array `SomeType[]` or not. When the delegate type signature does not have `params`, if the method has `params`, the method must apply in its unexpanded form. For example. If the method is `static bool Meth(params string[] args) { ... }`, then you can say `Predicate<string[]> p1 = Meth;`, but you can't expand, so it wont work with `Predicate<string> p2 = Meth;`.